# Simple Product attribute value is Visible on admin panel but shown empty on frontend

Tags: frontend, custom-attributes

I am having a weird problem. I have a delivery method attribute and it is filled by values. When I want to get that attribute for simple products I see it on 90% of the products and there is no problem. But for the rest I can not see that attribute value. I did print the simple product out which does not show the value and the attribute is really empty. But when I check it on Admin panel for the very same product I see that it is selected. To be sure I select it again and save it but still no value shown on frontend only for some of the products.

Is there anyone who had the same problem and who knows the solution of that?

I am using Magento 1.7.2 and attribute settings are OK since I am getting the value for most of the products.

Comment: did you rebuild your indexes?

Comment: Yep, several times already. I developed alot with Custom attributes but this is happening for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the product, somehow magento gave me simple products most of the time but in weird cases it gave me the configurable product, and since the configurable product does not have the option I was not able to get it. I changed the place of my code to be able to get simple product all the time. That worked out well.